# I'm stuck in Application.EnterPlayMode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I put this script in, this message pops up and I can't go next

**Unity 2021.3.15f1**

**Windows 10**

**Project name: 포둥**

[application.enterplaymode/ wating for Unyty's code to finish excuting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fubPo.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class podungsay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Textbox;
    public bool sayingf;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text sayingtext;
    public GameObject openmouth;
    public GameObject closemouth;

    IEnumerator OnType(float interval, string Say, float wait)
    {
        sayingf = true;
        foreach (char item in Say)
        {
            sayingtext.text += item;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(wait);
        sayingf = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (sayingf == true)
        {
            Textbox.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Textbox.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator mouth()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            while (sayingf == true)
            {
                openmouth.SetActive(false);
                closemouth.SetActive(true);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
                openmouth.SetActive(true);
                closemouth.SetActive(false);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
            }
            openmouth.SetActive(true);
            closemouth.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(mouth());
    }
}
```

So I changed the version to 2021.3.17f1 but still got this message
What's wrong with the command?
(Use Google translator)

Comment: I guess because `sayingf` is false on initial.

Comment: If `sayingf` is `false` initially you immediately enter an infinite `while (true)` without any `yield return` within it -> complete freeze of the Unity main thread

Answer (score 0):

It is stuck because you are using a `while` which never ends. Leading to an **infinite loop**.

Use the `Update()` Method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Right here:

```
IEnumerator mouth()
{
    while (true)
    {
        while (sayingf == true)
        {
            openmouth.SetActive(false);
            closemouth.SetActive(true);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
            openmouth.SetActive(true);
            closemouth.SetActive(false);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.7f);
        }
        openmouth.SetActive(true);
        closemouth.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

When "sayingf" is false, it will set openmouth to be active and closemouse to be inactive, and then it will repeat from the `while (true)`, causing an infinite loop. You need to add a delay. You can use `yield return 0` or `yield return null` to wait for one frame to pass.

Also note that `sayingf == true` is a sin. This is your warning. The next infraction, I will resort to violence.

when using `bool == true`, either of these will happen:
`true == true` which will become `true`.
`false == true` which will become `false`.
You can just write `if (sayingf)` as `== true` isn't doing anything to the bool.